# send data array (same key values) using php curl

Tags: php, django, post, curl

I am sending a list of names and emails.

I am trying to create with curl the same functionality as in this form

```
<form method="post" action='http://url'>        
    name: <input type="text" name="name" value='name1'>
    email:<input type="text" name="email" value='email1'>
    name: <input type="text" name="name" value='name2'>
    email: <input type="text" name="email" value='email2'>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

i want to use the same key so i can use django

```
names = request.POST.getlist('name')
```

to get all the names in a list.

Now i am trying to do the same as in the form with php curl

```
$ch = curl_init();
$curlConfig = array(
CURLOPT_URL            => "http://url",
CURLOPT_POST           => true,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => array(
            'name' => 'name1',
            'email' => 'name1@email',
            'name' => 'name2',
            'email' => 'name2@email',
            ),
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print $result;
curl_close($ch);
```

and it doesnt work, it only get the last 2 values.
it is because the array is associative and so the last values override the previous ones.

Comment: I think CURL post data works a bit different since you're trying to create an array of name and email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i finally did was using a string instead of php assoicative array

```
$ch = curl_init();
$curlConfig = array(
CURLOPT_URL            => "http://url",
CURLOPT_POST           => true,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => "name=name1&emailname1@email&name=name2&email=name2@email"
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print $result;
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, array keys must be unique.  The second 'name' overwrites the data in the first 'name' so you would need a slightly different scheme.

Comment: Comine both your answers please.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use something like this.  Do you have a way to make a dump of the data in the Django script?

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => array(
    array(
            'name' => 'name1',
            'email' => 'name1@email',
         ),
    array(
            'name' => 'name2',
            'email' => 'name2@email',
         )
)
```