# php curl send multiple data under one key

Tags: php, select, curl

How to send data via `curl` which is under select tag? I can't find answer, please help, browser's procedure as follows:

```
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryEbHiNmjjU3pgp1Tb

------WebKitFormBoundaryEbHiNmjjU3pgp1Tb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="allVolumeCountries"

6
------WebKitFormBoundaryEbHiNmjjU3pgp1Tb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="allVolumeCountries"

13
```

P.S: I don't have access to source, so don't advise me to change to something like `allVolumeCountries[]`

Comment: Why do you need to use curl? curl can be used with php if you need to post some data using server side programming. but if you are on client side - you stated select tag - form should work.

Comment: Sorry dude, but it's not answer. Sometimes people have certain tasks, and in my case we need automation.

Comment: yes it's called a "comment" I'm trying to understand what you are trying to achieve. are you going to use post method?

Comment: yes, post method, using this curl class (https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class)

Comment: See http://scraperblog.blogspot.nl/2013/07/php-curl-multipart-form-posting.html

Comment: Thank you Hans Zandbelt, idea is good, bu not solution in my case. Found some articles http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549237/sending-multipart-form-data-through-curl-website-says-no-picture-provided. Also found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903657/send-data-array-same-key-values-using-php-curl. And finally for those who will face exact problem, in curl class mentioned above by me, modify line 429 (http_build_multi_query function) to something like this: $brackets = $is_array_assoc ? '[' . $k . ']' : ''; Problem solved